# Retrieving data from arrays in Java for Custom Scripts

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am attempting to create a custom script.

```
_source": {
                "_boost": "1.5",
                "bid": "60697",
                "name": "Brick",
                "address": "3095 33rd St",
                "city": "Astoria",
                "state": "NY",
                "zip": "11103",
                "tags": "Restaurant,Italian",
                "location": [
                    {
                        "lat": 40.76359,
                        "lon": -73.921684
                    }
                ]}
```

I am tryin to retrieve the lat and lon fields in Java using the DocLookup class. Usually I would just do doc().field("name") to get, for example, the name.

How would I go about getting the lat and lon in a custom script given my document structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double[] lats = ((GeoPointDocFieldData) doc().field("name")).getLats();
double[] lons = ((GeoPointDocFieldData) doc().field("name")).getLons();
```